# Sharing data between angular libraries

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, angular-library

I have created three libraries in angular 10: two are custom components, to be included within my application (angular 11), and a third library (service) aimed at sharing data that I will use to pass information between the first two libraries.

In the first library I defined a service that activates the next event of the observable.

After subscribing to the observable in both libraries (inside the `ngOnInit` of the component), the problem is that in the second library I cannot intercept the observable data.

The demonstration is given by the console.log statement contained in SecondLibrary.component.ts which returns nothing.

sharingDataLibrary

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharingDataService {
private id: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(undefined);
sharedId = this.id.asObservable();
constructor() { }
sendId(id: number) {
      this.id.next(id);
    }
}
```

FirstLibrary.service.ts

```
import { SharingDataService } from 'sharingDataLibrary';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirstLibraryService {
constructor(private _sharingDataService : SharingDataService ) {
}

public goToSecondLibrary(id) {
    console.log(id);
    this._sharingDataService.sendId(id);
  }
}
```

SecondLibrary.component.ts

```
import { SharingDataService } from 'sharingDataLibrary';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'second-library',
  templateUrl: './second-library.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second-library.component.scss']
})
export class SecondLibraryComponent implements OnInit {
sharedIdSubscription: Subscription;
constructor(private _sharingDataService : SharingDataService ) {
    }
ngOnInit(): void {
this.sharedIdSubscription = this._sharingDataService.sharedId.subscribe(id => {
      console.log(id);
      }
    });
}
```

The demonstration is given by the `console.log` statement contained in `SecondLibrary.component.ts` which returns nothing.

Comment: It is probably a matter of timing. Are you sure that the `ngOnInit` of `SecondLibraryComponent` is run before the `goToSecondLibrary(id)` is invoked?

Comment: No it's not a matter of timing. I tried adding `setTimeout` to `ngOnInit` but nothing. The `ngOnInit` is invoked because at the start of the application the `console.log` returns me `undefined`, after when I invoke the event that updates the observable it no longer returns anything. I thought it was a library build problem. The libraries were implemented in angular 10 and were included in an angular 11 application.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have more than one `SharingDataService` instance alive. This should not happen since the service is declared as `providedIn: 'root'`, but maybe is also declared in the `providers` array of some module or Component. You can add a `console.log` in the constructor of the `SharingDataService` and see if more than one instance is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. thanks to your last comment I solved it

Answer (score 0):

In your sharingDataLibrary, instead of :

> ...
> sharedId = this.id.asObservable();
> ...

try :

> import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
> ...
> sharedId = this.id.asObservable().pipe(share());
> ...

From the rxjs documentation :

> share : Returns a new Observable that multicasts (shares) the original
> Observable. As long as there is at least one Subscriber this
> Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers
> have unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from the source Observable.
> Because the Observable is multicasting it makes the stream hot. This
> is an alias for multicast(() => new Subject()), refCount().

Comment: I do not think `share` is required since the source is a Subject which is multicast by definition

Comment: @Picci just saw your comment. good catch !